# структура кода сайта

Tags: html, css, modx

подскажите, почему выводит не структурировано?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Либо MODX сжимает, либо у файла просто сбились отступы. В любом случае сама разметка будет работать нормально.

Comment: в modx поставил глобальное кеширование + кеширование бд + MinifyX может з-за этого? самое интересное что на некоторых страницах код структурирован

Comment: @Alsero скорее всего в MinifyX,